# String split on column or row in matrix with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, numpy, matrix, group-by

What is the best manner to do a `re.split` on a column within a matrix.
I am interested in doing this in order to conserve different annotations or labels associated with the characters within the string that is in the column of the matrix.

Here is what I have so far to illustrate my point:

```
from re import split
from numpy import vstack, zeros

text = 'This is a line of text.  It will need to be split into sentences.'
# binary annotations of characters (1 denotes a character of interest which belongs to a word of interest)
bin_ann = zeros(len(text))
# This is just to label some of the words in the text
text_to_label = ['text', 'sentences']
for l in text_to_label:
    start = text.find(l)
    end = start + len(l)
    bin_ann[start:end] = 1

# we can zip these together and make a matrix such that each character is now labeled.
z = zip(list(text), bin_ann)
nz = vstack(z)
# This is our lebeled text matrix
print(nz)
print(nz[:,0])

s = split('(\.\s+)', nz[:,0])
print(s)
```

This yields the following output:

```
[['T' '0.0']
 ['h' '0.0']
 ['i' '0.0']
 ['s' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['i' '0.0']
 ['s' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['a' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['l' '0.0']
 ['i' '0.0']
 ['n' '0.0']
 ['e' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['o' '0.0']
 ['f' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['t' '1.0']
 ['e' '1.0']
 ['x' '1.0']
 ['t' '1.0']
 ['.' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['I' '0.0']
 ['t' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['w' '0.0']
 ['i' '0.0']
 ['l' '0.0']
 ['l' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['n' '0.0']
 ['e' '0.0']
 ['e' '0.0']
 ['d' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['t' '0.0']
 ['o' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['b' '0.0']
 ['e' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['s' '0.0']
 ['p' '0.0']
 ['l' '0.0']
 ['i' '0.0']
 ['t' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['i' '0.0']
 ['n' '0.0']
 ['t' '0.0']
 ['o' '0.0']
 [' ' '0.0']
 ['s' '1.0']
 ['e' '1.0']
 ['n' '1.0']
 ['t' '1.0']
 ['e' '1.0']
 ['n' '1.0']
 ['c' '1.0']
 ['e' '1.0']
 ['s' '1.0']
 ['.' '0.0']]
['T' 'h' 'i' 's' ' ' 'i' 's' ' ' 'a' ' ' 'l' 'i' 'n' 'e' ' ' 'o' 'f' ' '
 't' 'e' 'x' 't' '.' ' ' ' ' 'I' 't' ' ' 'w' 'i' 'l' 'l' ' ' 'n' 'e' 'e'
 'd' ' ' 't' 'o' ' ' 'b' 'e' ' ' 's' 'p' 'l' 'i' 't' ' ' 'i' 'n' 't' 'o'
 ' ' 's' 'e' 'n' 't' 'e' 'n' 'c' 'e' 's' '.']
['This', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'line', ' ', 'of', ' ', 'text', '.', '', '  ', 'It', ' ', 'will', ' ', 'need', ' ', '
to', ' ', 'be', ' ', 'split', ' ', 'into', ' ', 'sentences', '.', '']
```

I would like to maintain the annotation-character matrix while grouping the tokens together.  Therefore, the desired output would likely be something such as this:

```
[ ['This' 0.0] [' ' 0.0] ['a' 0.0] ... ['text' 1.0] ...['sentences' 1.0] ['.' 0.0] ]
```

Comment: It would be easier to just match words and optional period `(\w+)(\s*[.])?` You could then construct your output array. If $2 has length, you've hit a period.

Comment: Wouldn't this task be a lot simpler with lists than arrays?

Comment: @hpaulj I'm not sure how simply using lists would help, but it may make it easier to read if I used lists.  It definitely does not solve the problem of conserving length and knowing locations of splits when splitting the text.

Comment: Which version of python? The call to `split` gives me a `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` in both 3.6 and 2.7 (2.7 says `buffer` instead of `bytes-like object`)

Comment: Also, your desired output looks more like an annotation-word matrix than an annotation-character matrix.

Comment: @Elliot That is the end goal for this, but it starts as a character level annotation, which hopefully I can condense after.

Comment: Also, I'm using python 3.5.2 which is packaged with Anaconda